Is this the proof the the Bayes classifier is optimal?
In"Introduction to statistical learning" they say that the proof that the Bayes classifier is optimal is outside the scope of the book:

In "Elements of statistical learning" the have this:

I am wondering if the proof they are saying is out of the scope of the book in "Introduction to statistical learning", is what is what is provided in the second picture?

Yes, that is indeed the correct proof.
My guess would be that they avoid this fairly simple proof because they feel that it goes into too much detail, and they are worried about confusing their reader. There's nothing particularly tricky about this result: you just need good understanding of the various mathematical objects under consideration.
In full generality, given a loss function $L$, there is an associated bayes estimator that minimizes the expected prediction error and that is computed from the conditional distribution of $Y|X=x$.
